# Python: How to count items in a specific column

Tags: python

I have to count the number of items (separated by a "/") in a specific column of a csv file.

Example csv chart:

```
Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4
1      A/B/C   1      1
2      E       2      2
3      Z/F     3      3
4      G       4      4
```

So I would need to count A,B,C,E,Z,F,G from Col2 only and I need to make sure that "Col2" doesn't get counted in the total. My problem is that "Col2" is getting counted into the final number...

The answer should be 7.

This is what I have so far:
    import csv

```
total = {}
with open('result.csv') as f:
    rows = csv.reader(f)
    for line in rows:
        total = 0
        for num in line.strip().split('/'):
            total =+ int(num)

    print total
```

Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: why you use semicolon in your code, since there isn't a semicolon present in our file? is that the file tab separated or semicolon separated.

Comment: is that the lines are  tab separated?

Comment: i mean what exists between each column? `Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4`

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. A "," exists between each column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about just counting the number of slashes in each line?

```
total = 0
for line in rows:
    numSlashes = line.count('/')
    if numSlashes > 0:
        total += numSlashes + 1
```

*Edit*: Use the logic above if you want to count the items *only* when a slash appears. If you want to count single items too, but just ignore the first line, then just skip the first line, e.g.

```
for line in rows[1:]:
    numSlashes = line.count('/')
    total += numSlashes + 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the input! I just tried it out now and when I printed the total I got a list of zeros uhoh

Comment: In your code in the OP, you reset the total inside the loop. Try getting rid of that line and setting the total to zero outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

This will do splitting only on the column 2 which contain a forward slash and then it would find the length of the spitted items and it would add the length to the count variable.

```
with open('file') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader, None)
    count = 0
    for line in reader:
        count += len(line[1].split('/'))
    print(count)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This is really good except it's not catching the lines that only have one item in it

Comment: Oh! wait I just added a line for 
else: 
count = count + 1

And it works except my total is 1 more than it should be (I think it's counting the "Col2" line), is there a way to not count the column header?

Answer (score 0):

If you actually have comma separated values:

```
with open('in.csv') as f:
    next(f) # skip header
    rows = csv.reader(f)
    print(sum(len(row[1].split("/")) for row in rows))
7
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library to solve this with a one liner, using the [`get_dummies()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.get_dummies.html) method:

```
>>> import pandas
>>> pandas.read_csv('result.csv')
>>> df.Col2.str.get_dummies(sep="/").values.sum()
7
```

It can be a good idea if you need to do more than just counting, for instance if you need the number of time each item appears.

```
>>> df.Col2.str.get_dummies(sep="/").sum(0)

A    1
B    1
C    1
E    1
F    1
P    1
Z    1
dtype: int64
```